# Search engine with colored search word

Tags: php, mysql

I want to search engine with LIKE keyword and i want to colored searched word.
My code is:

```
$result1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM archives1 where title like '%$search%' || author like '%$search%'") or die (mysql_error());
     while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1))
        {

            extract($row1);
     echo" <table width='456' height='151'  style='table-layout:fixed;'>
        <tr><td align='center'>Archives</td></tr>
       <tr><td height='38'><b>Section:</b></td><td width='334'>$section</td></tr>
       <tr><td height='38'><b>Title:</b></td><td width='334'>$title</td></tr>
       <tr><td height='38'><b>Author:</b></td><td width='334'>$author</td></tr>
       <tr><td height='38'><b>Country:</b></td><td width='334'>$country</td></tr>
       <tr><td height='38'><b>Page Number:</b></td><td width='334'>$pgno</td></tr>";
```

If i want to search any word with above code then it gives true answer but i want answer with colored text. Only search word should be colored.

How can it be possible?
I have no idea.

Comment: `$title = str_replace($search, '<span style="color:red;">'.$search.'</span>', $title);`

Comment: btw: Don't use mysql_*, it's deprecated. Better switch to mysqli_* or PDO, see http://php.net/manual/de/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: where it will be use?

Comment: After `extract($row1);`

Comment: But search color is case sensitive. If i search 'and' it search 'and' with color. But if I search 'And' then it gives 'and' without color.

Comment: Use `str_ireplace()` instead of `str_replace()`

Answer (score 0):

use a preg_replace to replace the searched text with a span and add a class to it.

```
$text = 'sample text';
$query = 'text';
$text = preg_replace('/('.$query.')/','<span class="highlight">$1</span>',$text);

echo $text;
```

use the highlight class to style the result.

Comment: Why regular expressions when it's a simple text search? What happens if $query contains parentheses?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple function to highlight arbitrary text:

```
// Replace string and highlight it
function highlight_words($string, $words, $css_class)
 {
    //convert searched word to array
    $words = array($words);
    //cycle
    foreach ( $words as $word )  {
        $string = str_ireplace($word, '<span class="'.$css_class.'">'.$word.'</span>', $string);
    }
    /*** return the highlighted string ***/
    return $string;
 }
```

**Example usage:**

```
$string = 'This text will highlight PHP and SQL and sql but not PHPRO or MySQL or sqlite';
$words = array('php', 'sql');
$string =  highlightWords($string, $words, 'highlight');
```